# Eclipse Paho Python Client not connecting

Tags: python, eclipse, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

When I try and run the code below the screen remains blank and doesn't indicate the client is connected to the broker.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

broker = "localhost"
#define what happens after connection
def on_connect(rc):
    print "Connection returned result: "+str(rc)
#On recipt of a message do action
def on_message(msg):
    n = msg.payload
    t = msg.topic
    print t+" "+str(n)
# create broker
mqttc = mqtt.Client()

#define callbacks
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect

#connect
mqttc.connect(broker, 1883, 60)

#Subscribe to topic
mqttc.subscribe("/sensor/rfid", 2)

#keep connected
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

I can verify that the broker is running properly since I was able to run

```
mosquitto_sub -t /sensor/rfid
```

and get messages sent from the MyMQTT app on my android phone.
I also forgot to mention this is all on the raspberry pi with mosquitto, mosquitto-clients, and paho-mqtt installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the official example on the Paho site; https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/ or more here; http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.python.git/tree/examples

As it looks like you are missing a few parameters in the function on_connect()

Comment: I modified my code to add the missing parameters and tried the official example. Neither of them worked.

Comment: What version do you have installed? ```pip show paho-mqtt``` ? Also if you use the official example with the public mqtt server ```iot.eclipse.org``` do you have the same issue? And what version is your mqtt broker?

Comment: That command doesn't work for me and i'm able to connect to the public mqtt server just fine. The broker i'm using is mosquitto version 0.15

Comment: Upgrade the broker then, that is an older one. (latest is 1.3.5) Follow this guide on adding the repo and upgrading it, http://jpmens.net/2013/09/01/installing-mosquitto-on-a-raspberry-pi/ should work after that.

Comment: I updated it just like you said and it worked! Thanks for your help!